# Trying to parse data out in Oracle using regexp_substr

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

So I am trying to parse out data from this table that has a single identifier (file_name) and there are different attributes such as first_name, last_name, date_of_birth. The catch here is that the other non-identifier columns (such as first_name, last_name, etc.) have multiple entries delimited by im guessing a chr(10). Some of these fields can also be null (as DOB is shown below)
So for example:
The original data will have: filename.xml johnjacob schmidtmiller, 1-02-03
i need it to become:
filename.xml john schmidt 1-02-03
filename.xml jacob miller null

What i have is as follows:

```
    select file_name
          , regexp_substr(first_name, '([^chr(10)]*)(chr(10)|$)', 1, level, null, 1) as first_name
         , regexp_substr(last_name, '([^chr(10)]*)(chr(10)|$)', 1, level, null, 1) as last_name
         , regexp_substr(dob, '([^chr(10)]*)(chr(10)|$)', 1, level, null, 1) as dob
     from TABLE
  connect by level <= regexp_count(first_name, chr(10)) + 1
      and prior file_name = file_name
      and prior sys_guid() is not null
    order by file_name
```

I am currently only returning the first first name / last name / dob etc. for each file name. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Please find (google) and read the documentation for the `REGEXP_SUBSTR` function. You will see that it states explicitly that, by default, it treats the beginning and the end of a LINE as the beginning and the end of the whole input string. This default behavior can be overridden, in the fifth argument (which right now is `NULL` in your code). Namely, change `NULL` to `'m'` (in all the calls to the function) and run again.

From the documentation:

*'m' treats the source string as multiple lines. Oracle interprets ^ and $ as the start and end, respectively, of any line anywhere in the source string, rather than only at the start or end of the entire source string. If you omit this parameter, Oracle treats the source string as a single line.*

**Added**:  Moreover, when we want `chr(10)` to represent the line feed character, it should NOT be within quoted substrings.

```
[^chr(10)]
```

(within a quoted string) doesn't mean any character OTHER THAN LF (line feed). Instead, it means any character OTHER THAN c, h, r, 1, 0, ( and ).

Rather, the search pattern must alternate between quoted strings and CHR(10) OUTSIDE quotes, using concatenation.

```
'([^chr(10)]*)(chr(10)|$)'
```

should, instead, be

```
'([^'  ||  chr(10)  ||  ']*)('  ||  chr(10)  ||  '|$)'
```

Note also, importantly, that we can be liberal (flexible) with spaces OUTSIDE quoted strings (for legibility), but not WITHIN the strings. The single-quote after the caret symbol `^`, for example, must be IMMEDIATELY after the caret; if we add a space there, "for legibility", the search pattern will become incorrect. The concatenation operators `||` are outside the quoted fragments, so we can add spaces around them liberally.

Comment: sorry. I did try to read it but the documentation seemed too confusing and seemed like from the documentation was inconsistent on how many inputs it accepted. maybe I'm overthinking it?

Comment: @icerabbit - How many inputs it accepts depends on you Oracle version. At least since Version 10.1 the fifth argument has been present. What is newer (since 11.1) is the sixth argument, the back reference that does most of the work in your example. (Before Oracle 11.1 the solution would not have worked!) But the explanation for the fifth argument, where you have NULL now, is the same in all versions.

Comment: So a sample data entry that i have for first_name is: john(chr(10))jacob. My function seems to only be looking for data in between the CRs. How do make it start from the beginning of the string, return that part, then look for whatever comes after or before the CRs?

Comment: it seems like when I use the dump function with chr(10), it doesnt like it. I was using the function correctly all along. So i just manipulated the original data set and replaced them with a different character  and the function works 100% as it should. Not sure why it was doing that , any idea why? Thanks so much!

Comment: @icerabbit - I think I see what is happening, I will add to my Answer.